# jQuery copy one <select> value to another and vice versa

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

I am using below code to copy one select value to another:

```
    jQuery("#billing_country").change(function(){
        jQuery("#shipping_country").val(jQuery("#billing_country").val()).change();

    });
```

This works one way. I would also like to be able to copy a change in value from `#shipping_country` to affect a similar change in value in `#billing_country` (a.k.a. the other way round).

The point is, using `change()` (which is necessary to actually change the select) in this way creates an infinite loop. What other options are there to update the select's values without using `change()`? Setting `selectedIndex` does work, but does not trigger the element to immediately update as `change()` does.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/change/) about the `change()` method.

You do not need to call the change event after changing the value with `.val(value)` method.

Here is my [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpgvvN) of the solution.

Your problem is that if you change one select you are changing the value AND then you call the change method (this will trigger the change event of the other select). Then the other select will execute the change event handler and change the value of the first select and call the change event there too. And then you are at the beginning redoing this loop all the time til the stack is full.